# Real-time collaborative editor with Atmosphere

Tags: java, mysql, json, real-time, atmosphere

I would like to have a real-time collaborative editor (similar to Google Docs). I managed to implement this:https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Meteor,-WebSocket-and-Long-Polling.

So now i'm able to send text between two clients. But i have some difficulties to understand how to manage a collaborative document/editor.

I've read about operational transformation. So what do you think about following setup:

There are three clients:
Client A, Client B, Client C

All three are connected via websockets. All the changes are send to the API (it will be a full json object). The clients receive the json object and according to that they /insert/delete/update content. At this point nothing is saved to the database. My easiest way would be, that only Client A (he is dominant) saves to the database on every change (including the changes from the other clients). With this solution i would not have to implement OT at the API level. If Client A leaves, another Client would get dominant and save to the database.

My only issue right now is, that there is no (in my mind) easy solution to handle the OT between the clients.

Do you have any suggestions? Does this solution makes sense or is this totally crap?

My Techstack so far:

Backbone / jQuery

MySQL

Java Servlet / Tomcat 7 (Jetty is better with WS - will implement that later)

Would be cool if it fits with this stack ;)

Best
Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so i kind of solved it myself. There is a great project out there called webstrate. If you want to do rich-text-editing in real-time you should really check this out.

Best
Fabian

Comment: Oops I just figured out your backend is Java. Then you may want to take a look [Cettia](http://cettia.io/projects/cettia-java-server/1.0.0-Alpha1/) too.